# suburi not working with nginx , it gave me `No route matches ` exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

I need to run my Rails app under an sub-uri with /browse/

here's my company's root domain `WEBSITE.COM`

and my app's root domain should be starting with `https://WEBSITE.COM/browse`

However I alway got the  exception `No route matches` if I add `scope ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] do` in the routes file.

What should I do to fix the problem ?

## ENV

- ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']=/browse/

## routes.rb

```
scope ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] do
    get 'browse/category_detail'
    get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

## application.rb

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.relative_url_root = ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']
  end
```

## Error in production log

```
I, [2015-10-20T07:07:15.956058 #30522]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-20 07:07:15 +0000
F, [2015-10-20T07:07:15.957575 #30522] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
```

## nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name WEBSITE.COM;
    location /browse {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/puma.broswe.sock:/;
    }
}%
```

＃update

## Access Log

If I remove the `scope ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` in the routes.

Everything looks fine But the url helper will be broken,

That is the session_destroy_url will be `https://WEBSITE.COM/session/destroy`  but not `https://WEBSITE.COM/browse/session/destroy`

### when I tried to access `https://WEBSITE.COM/browse`

```
  I, [2015-10-22T00:14:18.847598 #22300]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-22 00:14:18 +0000
  F, [2015-10-22T00:14:18.848971 #22300] FATAL -- :
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
    actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
    rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    dragonfly (0.9.15) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
    rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
    rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
    rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
    rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
    rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
    railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
    rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
    rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
    rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
    puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:51:in `call'
    puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
    puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
    puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
    puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
    puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

### When I tried to access `https://WEBSITE.COM/browse/browse/1`

```
I, [2015-10-22T00:15:32.391853 #22300]  INFO -- : Started GET "/browse/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-22 00:15:32 +0000
F, [2015-10-22T00:15:32.393190 #22300] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/1"):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  dragonfly (0.9.15) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/configuration.rb:51:in `call'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
  puma (2.11.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

## Nginx log

> https://WEBSITE.COM//browse

```
    10.0.0.97 - - [25/Oct/2015:09:24:45 +0000] "GET /browse HTTP/1.1" 404 715 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
    10.0.0.97 - - [25/Oct/2015:09:24:45 +0000] "GET /browse HTTP/1.1" 404 715 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
```

> https://WEBSITE.COM//browse/123

```
    10.0.0.97 - - [25/Oct/2015:09:25:12 +0000] "GET /browse/123 HTTP/1.1" 404 715 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: everything looks fine, did u find the solution ?

Comment: please post the error log too; make sure this typo is intentional `broswe.sock`

Comment: Hi the typo is fine, because my puma socket can receive the connection.

Comment: @illusionist please see my update, and what is the appropriate keyword for the problem `sub-uri`, `sub-domain` or `sub folder` because the information is so sparse thanks

Comment: @newBike, did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> ….com/browse/browse/1

This is because you make nginx strip the `/browse` part from `$uri` the way that you use [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect):

```
location /browse {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/puma.broswe.sock:/;
}
```

If your intention is *NOT* to strip `/browse` when the thing goes upstream, then this is what you should have instead:

```
location /browse {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/puma.broswe.sock:/browse;
}
```

Or this:

```
location /browse {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/puma.broswe.sock:;
}
```

Yes, the extra trailing [`/`](http://slash.su/) in the original is what's causing you the trouble of missing `/browse` in the upstream.